# Aws amplify cli - awsconfiguration.json missing

Tags: android, aws-cli

I follow the basic tutorial for adding aws services to android app from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#android-java)

I noticed that after ***amplify init*** command *awsconfiguration.json*
Is not generated in res/raw, although it recognized that it is android project and went through all the steps. I do not see what I am missing, this should be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run **amplify push** after you run **amplify init**.

**amplify push** will place the awsconfiguration.json in res\raw folder.

> Your project has been successfully initialized and connected to the
>   cloud!
>
> Some next steps: "amplify status" will show you what you've added
>   already and if it's locally configured or deployed "amplify 
>   add" will allow you to add features like user login or a backend API
>   "amplify push" will build all your local backend resources and
>   provision it in the cloud "amplify publish" will build all your local
>   backend and frontend resources (if you have hosting category added)
>   and provision it in the cloud
>
> Pro tip: Try "amplify add api" to create a backend API and then
>   "amplify publish" to deploy everything

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn